# How to infer the return type of a function?

Tags: rust, type-inference

The return type of a block is inferred.

```
fn main() {
    let x = { 5 };
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

But when I give the block a name, I have to specify a type.

```
fn five() -> i32 {
    5
}

fn main() {
    let x = five();
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

How can I avoid selecting a type?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot. Rust [explicitly prohibits this by design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977576/5903309).

However, for large and complex return types, you have the following options:

- Use a closure instead - As it is local, it is allowed to infer its type
- Return a boxed type
- Return [an abstract type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md)

You can see a practical example of these in the answer for [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535594/5903309)

Comment: why is the answere "u cannot" when rocket applications use "_" symbol with the launch function to infer return types

Comment: @clockw0rk could you elaborate where this happens? The [current code for Rocket::launch](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.5.0-rc.3/core/lib/src/rocket.rs#L901) does not seem to use the mechanism you describe.

Comment: read it during following the rocket tutorials on the page. i will look at it tomorrow and update this