# Returning a type in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a trait(StringToTable) that return a struct with an implementation of another trait(Table).

When I have read this answer [How to infer the return type of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347962/how-to-infer-the-return-type-of-a-function), I tried the "boxed type" approach, but without success.

I don't know the struct type on call my StringToTable, so I can't use approaches like 'to_table< T >' or 'StringToTable< T >' ..

Playground with the error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cac035a6e6357c204156fab13449e865

My code:

1° approach:

```rust
fn to_table(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex>>>;
```

I got:

```rust
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
  --> src/main.rs:18:75
   |
18 |     fn to_table(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex>>>;
   |                                                        ----------------   ^^^^^^^^^
   |                                                        |                  |
   |                                                        |                  additional non-auto trait
   |                                                        |                  trait alias used in trait object type (additional use)
   |                                                        first non-auto trait
   |                                                        trait alias used in trait object type (first use)
```

2° approach:

```rust
fn to_table2(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<T>>> where T: DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex;
```

I got:

```rust
error[E0412]: cannot find type `T` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:68
   |
20 |     fn to_table2(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<T>>> where T: DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex;
   |                                                                    ^ not found in this scope
```

** My code has been simplified

What I'm trying to do: receive a random name on a tcp server and got the equivalent struct for it.

Answer (score 0):

In the second approach, you can fix the compilation error by declaring the type parameter T. You can do this on the function or on the trait.

On the function:

```
fn to_table2<T>(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<T>>> where T: DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex;
```

On the trait:

```
pub trait StringToTable<T> where T: DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex {

    fn to_table2(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<T>>>;
}
```

Another option is to use an associated type:

```
pub trait StringToTable {
    type T : DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex;

    fn to_table2(table: String) -> Option<Box<dyn Table<Self::T>>>;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the struct type on call my StringToTable, so I cant use approach's like 'to_table< T >' or 'StringToTable< T >' ...

The to_table function can return Any implentation of the traits 'DeserializeOwned + Serialize + SearchIndex'

Comment: I think someone needs to know the struct type used. The type parameter should be added where it is known. Maybe associated types (see edit above) help with that. Could you share an example of how you plan to use the Table and StringToTable traits?

Comment: The associated type works on the playgound. Later I will test with my real source. Thank you for now

Comment: I tested the associated type, but now my problem is on the implementation of this trait. I get the "error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object" for the DeserializeOwned and Serialize types. 
A new playgroud with the error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3fc55f9312c16d25cf5dc3d2fe3ba8a

Comment: What is the code in the implementation of `to_table`? Isn't there a concrete type that you can use for T? If not, maybe you can create a wrapper that includes the data and the required functions.

Comment: This is my implementation https://gist.github.com/fernandobatels/feef962ccecc56f2e6a78fb03ab9108e

Comment: How i can create a wrapper for this case?

Comment: In the example it looks like the `DbDriver` knows the type to create. Maybe you can add an associated type to the `DbDriver` to make it work? I might have been wrong about the possibility to create a wrapper. If I understand the restrictions in Rust correctly, it would be necessary to create a trait without any generic methods to be able to do it. One option would be to create a restricted trait that can only serialize from/to Json. Another option might be a trait that interacts with the (de-)serializer only via some intermediate data structures.