Rust Book Brown University Chapter 10.2 2nd Quiz Question 1
In Rust Book Brown University Chapter 10.2 2nd Quiz Question 1 states:

Determine whether the program will pass the compiler. If it passes, write the expected output of the program if it were executed.
use std::fmt::Display;
fn displayable<T: Display>(t: T) -> impl Display { t }
fn main() {
  let s = String::from("hello");
  let mut s2 = displayable(s);
  s2.push_str(" world");
  println!("{s2}");
}


Spoiler alert, it doesn't compile.
It's explained that it could compile if the return type was changed to T instead of impl Display.
This left me curious, I'm thinking the compiler will always be able to infer the type. The reason being that the return type of a function cannot be conditional (also stated in ch. 10.2) and thus the return type is either

Constant, always the same independent of any of the argument types
Same as one of the arguments (EDIT: or related to)

Am I wrong or are you simply forced to be explicit about the return type event though it could be inferred?
EDIT:
TLDR, I guess what I am trying to ask is: Does omitting the return type from the function signature (as shown) allow writing programs where at any point at compile-time it is ambiguous which type a function returns?
EDIT 2:
What I find a bit strange is that on this line let mut s2 = displayable(s); the compiler is clearly able to infer that s2 is a string, yet on the next line calling push_str on s2 will not compile.

Well, both…? It’s not true that a function’s return type is necessarily either of those things, but it is true that you have to specify a return type even when it can be inferred, but none of this seems relevant in the first place when the point of impl Display is to not guarantee any particular type (with use cases like having more flexibility to change the function’s implementation later).

The return type from Iterator::next is neither constant, nor the same as one of the arguments…

@Ry-, I don't see how a third option is possible. Could you provide an example?
Since Rust does type inference in other cases I was just curious why you wouldn't want it in this case or why it's not possible/hard

@cataclysmic as I pointed out in my comment above, the return type from Iterator::next is neither constant, nor the same as any argument.

@Jmb, I disagree, Iterator::next falls under point 2. same as one of the arguments. In case of Iterator::next has one argument which is self. Thus for a given iterator you know the return type (iterator of u32 for example).

@cataclysmic by your reasoning, function_a and function_b have the same return type in this playground: both have only one argument which has the same type so the return types must be the same, right?

@Jmb, hmm, not exactly. In that case the return type for function_a and function_b is constant and very explicit. The use of generics doesn't make the return type dynamic, instead it will compile separate functions for each type used in the program.
For fun I expanded upon your example as I wasn't entirely familiar with associated types: here.

It seems like you meant something different from what you said, which was that “the return type is [the] same as one of the arguments”.

Sorry about being unclear, I guess formulating point 2 as "Same or related to one of the arguments" would have been more precise. But anyway, we're sidetracking. What I am really asking is, in the case where the the return type is not explicitly stated (as in fn displayable), are there any cases where the actual return type is ambiguous at compile time or is it always inferable?

So the options are that the type is either related to or not related to one of the arguments. Yes. As for the other question, yes, there are cases where the type of an expression is ambiguous – one straightforward case is a call to a function whose return type is generic and not a function of its arguments, like .collect() or .into(). That isn’t why you have to specify most return types though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347962/how-to-infer-the-return-type-of-a-function

This is not really a compiler problem but rather a human one.
If the author of displayable wanted you to know it always returns the type that was given, they could've and should've written that. Likewise if it was something different entirely. However an impl Trait return type communicates to the user that is not a specific type and the only thing they can know about the return type is that it implements that trait.
Why would you want this? There are many facets of Rust's design that help enforce that code is robust in regards to changes (to an extent). An effect of its "orphan rules" for example limits trait implementations from trying to rely on the basis that some implementation does not exist since it may in the future. Through this lens, return an impl Trait gives a developer flexibility that the underlying type may change without it being a breaking change so long as it satisfies the signature.
This is also part of a philosophical design decision that Rust has taken: that you should fully be able to discern how a function can be used solely on its signature1. A function signature is a contractual barrier. This is a big part of how borrow checking works but it affects things like impl Trait too. If you were able to call .push_str() as shown in the code, then that is taking advantage of hidden information that isn't expressed through the signature.
1. Annoyingly, auto traits (like Send and Sync) do leak through -> impl Trait which is a breaking change hazard but the ergonomics of not doing that would be too poor.

Just noting that impl Trait in return type has another purpose: unnameable types (closures etc.).
