# How do I tell the compiler that my function terminates the program like process::exit()?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have the following function that includes some error recovery logic and the `process::exit(0)` in the end:

```
fn gracefully_shutdown() {
    // Do some logic for the recover
    process::exit(7);
}
```

I want to call that function in the error case but `match` complains about `incompatible arms`. But it does not complain when I write it explicitly into a match arm like the following:

```
fn handle_result(my_result: Result<i32, MyError>) -> i32 {
    match my_result {
        Ok(val) => val,
        //Err(_error) => { process::exit(0); } // Does not complain
        Err(_error) => {
            gracefully_shutdown();
        } // Does complain
    }
}
```

Is it really hard for the compiler to understand that `gracefully_shutdown()` contains `process::exit(0)` in itself?

I would expect that I could have written the code in this way:

```
fn handle_result(my_result: Result<i32, MyError>) -> i32 {
    match my_result {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(_error) => {
            gracefully_shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas to make this work?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c462f198ced7fcf69c38e361c7d1d635)

Comment: The "why doesn't it infer" question is answered here: [Differences in Type inference for closures and functions in rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24977365/3650362)

Comment: *gracefully_shutdown* — this is not really a "graceful shutdown"; the rest of your program never has a chance to clean up.

Comment: @Shepmaster, Yes I know that, it is the code that I will be change later on. Just wanted to know the main reason behind the compiler error. `Never type` is the key answer that I was looking for. However if you know good example for gracefully shutdown, i would be gladly look into this topic as well :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the signature of `gracefully_shutdown` to

```
fn gracefully_shutdown() -> ! {
    process::exit(7);
}
```

This will tell the compiler that this function **never** returns! The `!` is called the [never type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.never.html).

For more information see

- [Why does Rust have a "Never" primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832396/why-does-rust-have-a-never-primitive-type)

Comment: See also [Why would I use divergent functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31082098/155423).